# Why is decltype(member) not const while decltype((member)) is for const object and how does it impact function calls

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, member, template-argument-deduction

I don't understand the behavior of the following snippet, which is an MRE derived from actual code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// It merely returns its input, which is a reference
// could mutualize code for const and non const member function below
template <typename T>
T& Getter(T& i) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Getter, const int: "
              << std::is_same<T, const int>::value
              << " / int: " << std::is_same<T, int>::value << '\n';
    return i;
}

struct S {
    int val = -1;

    // Read/write access to the data for mutable object
    int& Get() {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << "non-const Get, val const int: "
                  << std::is_same<decltype(val), const int>::value
                  << " / int: " << std::is_same<decltype(val), int>::value
                  << '\n';
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << "const Get, (val) const int&: "
                  << std::is_same<decltype((val)), const int&>::value
                  << " / int&: " << std::is_same<decltype((val)), int&>::value
                  << '\n';
        return Getter(val);
    }

    // Read-only access to the data for const object
    int const& Get() const {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << "const Get, val int const: "
                  << std::is_same<decltype(val), const int>::value
                  << " / int: " << std::is_same<decltype(val), int>::value
                  << '\n';
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << "const Get, (val) int const&: "
                  << std::is_same<decltype((val)), const int&>::value
                  << " / int&: " << std::is_same<decltype((val)), int&>::value
                  << '\n';
        return Getter(val);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "---------------------\nconst\n";
    S const ks;
    std::cout << ks.Get() << '\n';
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/xafbq8Tcr)

The output is as follows:

```
---------------------
const
const Get, val const int: false / int: true
const Get, (val) const int&: true / int&: false
Getter, const int: true / int: false
```

`ks` is `const` thus I'm calling `S::Get() const`: OK 
Inside `S::Get() const` `decltype(val)` is `int` but `decltype((val))` is `const int&`: I find it peculiar. 
This has been addressed in:

- [Type of member variables in a const member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304843/type-of-member-variables-in-a-const-member-function)
- [C++11 why the type of 'decltype(x)' and 'decltype((x))' are different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363040/c11-why-the-type-of-decltypex-and-decltypex-are-different)
- [Result of decltype in const methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887690/result-of-decltype-in-const-methods)

This behavior is clearly defined in the standard (see the [human-friendly version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), especially 2-b)).

But I don't get the rationale behind this.

`Getter` is called on `val`, passed by reference, but `T` is deduced as `const int`, as if the argument was a reference to const lvalue (`const int &`).

I would have expected that it would be `decltype(val)` which will the "input" of the template argument deduction. 
In most situations, it seems that the difference is invisible, but when dealing with constness it's becoming critical, as in the provided snippet.

What detail am I missing? When passing an expression (possibly a single variable) to a function, what is the type of the expression "seen" by the function (which will impact template argument deduction but, also, possibly, overload resolution)?

It's obviously a basic question, but these subtleties nether occurred to me so far. The linked posts above are revolving about it, but I'm still missing what is actually happening at the function call.

Comment: Why do you quote the output with all those <br/> instead of placing it in its code block?

Comment: `val` is an identity, `(val)` is an expression. `decltype(identity)` and `decltype(expression)` behave differently as for the standard.

Comment: So, when passed to a function, it must be considered as an expression (which might be context dependent, contrary to an identity, as you're calling it). Saying it otherwise, when writing `foo(stg)`, it's `decltype((stg))` that is considered for argument matching, not `decltype(stg)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. A function argument is an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What detail am I missing ?** When passing an expression (possibly a single variable) to a function, what is the type of the expression "seen" by the function (which will impact template argument deduction but, also, possibly, overload resolution)?  **I'm still missing what is actually happening at function call.** `Getter` is called on `val`, passed by reference, but `T` is deduced as `const int`, as if the argument was a reference to const lvalue (`const int &`).

You're missing that when `val` is passed as a function argument in the function call `Getter(val)` is an expression with a value category *lvalue* with type `const int`. Note also that in the call `Getter(val)` the expression `val` has type `const int` because we're inside a *const member function*.

This is why `T` is deduced as `const int`.

---

Here is a **contrived example** to make this clear:

```
template<typename T> void f(T&){}
int main()
{
    const int i = 0;
    f(i); //T is deduced as const int. Note the argument `i` in `f(i)` is an expression with value category lvalue and is of type `const int`
}
```

Comment: Being nitpicking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415226/does-each-expression-in-c-have-a-non-reference-type and https://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2015/02/expressions-can-have-reference-type.html. expressions can have reference type.

Comment: In order to close the question completely, the "issue" is that `decltype` does not really return the type of its argument (see `decltype`) documentation. The actual behavior with respect to argument matching is simpler and as expected, as described in the answer.

Comment: @Oersted Updated(removed the sentence expressions can not have reference type)